# Issues with using the call_later function [asyncio]

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I have been having issues with task scheduling. In the first case I have this:

```
import asyncio

async def run():
    print("hi there")
    print("How are you")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(3, run)
    print("ye")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This only outputs `ye` to the console. And If I add `()` to `run` it gives an error

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(3, run())
    print("ye")
```

This also results in an error `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback ye`

Then I `await`ed `run()` like so:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(3, await run())
    print("ye")
```

This outputs:

```
hi there
How are you
ye
```

Which seems normal, but the problem with this is that it is ran immediately. Because I decided to do `await run()` which just executes the coroutine.

So I thought I should try it with a synchronous function to check if the type matters. Like this

```
def foo():
    print("hi this is foo")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(3, foo())
    print("ye")
```

Which outputs:

```
hi this is foo
ye
```

Which is the exact same result as when I did `await run()` changing it to `foo` from `foo()` only outputs `ye` just like when I passed in `run()` instead of `run`.
So I am extremely confused as to what I am supposed to do here.

Comment: Your first attempt is correct, however, nothing’s awaiting the execution of the function called later. The main event loop is only waiting for `main` to complete, as that’s all you told it to `run`. Either you run the loop forever, or you need to explicitly await that later task as well.

Comment: These are the things I've tried to get it to work. [Here](https://hatebin.com/bilorapvqq) is the link to the code.

Comment: `call_later` really only makes sense if you have a `run_forever` loop. If you're just running a single `async` function with `asyncio.run`, then the event loop only exists as long as that one function runs. Once it returns, the loop closes, and any scheduled tasks will never be executed. If you require a certain number of tasks to be executed and your loop must await all their completion, then you *need* a handle on your tasks and you *must* `await` them. If you need a 3 second pause, `await asyncio.sleep(3)` would be appropriate.

Comment: Oh, that is very good to know. And helpful. Thank you, very much.